# Display the biggest cylinder capacity of all the cars in C — structures

Tags: c, function, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char model[50], mark[50], color[50];
    int cylinderCap;
} car;

void read(car *cr, int *nr) {
    printf("Insert mark: ");
    (*nr)++;
    fflush(stdin);
    gets((cr + *nr)->mark);
    printf("Insert model: ");
    gets((cr + *nr)->model);
    printf("Insert color: ");
    gets((cr + *nr)->color);
    printf("Insert the cylinder capacity: ");
    scanf("%d", &((cr + *nr)->cylinderCap));
}

void display(car *cr, int nr) {
    printf("\n%-10s \t%-10s \t%-10s %d", (cr + nr)->mark, (cr + nr)->model,
           (cr + nr)->color, cr[nr].cylinderCap);
}

void search_model(car *cr, int *nr, char mod[50]) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= (*nr); i++)
        if(strcmp((cr + i)->model, mod) == 0)
            display(cr, i);
}

void search_cc(car *cr, int *nr, int cc) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= (*nr); i++)
        if((cr + i)->cylinderCap >= cc)
            display(cr, i);
}


void clear(car *cr, int *nr, char mod[50]) {
    int k = 0,i,j;

    for(i = 0; i <= (*nr); i++)
        if(strcmp((cr + i)->model, mod) == 0)
        {
            k++;
            for(j = i; j <= (*nr - k); j++)
                *(cr + j) = cr[j + 1];
        }
    *nr = *nr - k;
}


void main() {

    car cr[50];
    int opt, n = -1, i, cc = 1900;
    char mod[50];

    do{
        system("CLS");
        printf("1.Add a car\n");
        printf("2.Display cars\n");
        printf("3.Search a car after its model\n");
        printf("4.Display all the cars with cc > 1900\n");
        printf("5.Remove a car after its model\n");
        printf("6.Exit\n");
        printf("7.Display the biggest cyclinder capacity of all the cars\n");
        printf("Insert option: ");
        scanf("%d", &opt);

        switch(opt) {
            case 1:
                read(&cr[0], &n);
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\n%-10s \t%-10s \t%-10s %s", "mark", "Model", "color", "Capacity");

                for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
                    display(cr, i);
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("Insert model: ");
                scanf("%s", mod);
                printf("\n%-10s \t%-10s \t%-10s %s", "mark", "Model", "color", "Capacity");
                search_model(&cr[0], &n, mod);
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\n%-10s \t%-10s \t%-10s %s", "mark", "Model", "color", "Capacity");
                search_cc(&cr[0], &n, cc);
                break;

            case 5:
                printf("Insert the model you wish to delete: ");
                scanf("%s", mod);
                clear(&cr[0], &n, mod);
                break;

            case 6:
                break;

            case 7:
                break;

            default: printf("Error! Please try another option!\n");
                break;
        }
        getch();
    }while(opt != 6);

    getch();
}
```

This will display:

```
1.Add a car
2.Display cars
3.Search a car after its model
4.Display all the cars with cc > 1900
5.Remove a car after its model
6.Exit
7.Display the biggest cylinder capacity of all the cars
Insert option:
```

I don't have any idea how to do the last one, I don't even know how to begin!
I tried something like this, but with no success:

```
void maximum(car *cr, int *nr, int max) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <- (*nr); i++)
        if(((cr + i)->car) >=max))
            max = (cr + i)->car;
        display(max);
}
```

But it doesn't really work, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `conio.h` is not a standard header. `fflush(stdin)` is wrong. Never use `gets`. `void main` is wrong. Avoid `scanf` for user input. `scanf "%s"` is wrong. "Doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Also: `for(i = 0; i <- (*nr); i++)`. Maybe you meant to write `for(i = 0; i <= (*nr); i++)`?

Comment: Yes for(i = 0; i <= (*nr); i++)

@melpomene - that's the way they teach us at school! It may be wrong, but at this point I am just a beginner and for now I would like to focus on how to solve simple things!

Comment: Your school actually teaches `(cr + i)->car` instead of the more idiomatic `cr[i].car`? It looks particularly odd when you did this `*(cr + j) = cr[j + 1]`

Comment: "more idiomatic" is totally subjective, usually they teach both ways and everyone chooses according to his personal preference.

Comment: @user1908349 You can't focus on solving things by using broken methods.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: what Blastfurnace meant was *more correct* or *you're shooting yourself in the foot if you don't*. Because if you personally prefer to avoid the idiomatic (thanks to syntactic sugar) approach...you have poor taste.

Comment: @melpomene: `fflush(stdin)` is documented and defined behaviour on Windows (it is undefined behaviour on Unix). I gave you a URL once before (this one came up this time [MSDN `fflush()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).  Where `<conio.h>` is in use, it is not entirely reasonable to criticize the use of `fflush(stdin)` except to note that it is not portable — but those asking this level of question aren't currently worried about portability.

Comment: @sixlettervariables If a programmer prefers it, then why using the other way? One could say that you have poor taste if you do the opposite.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That just makes Windows wrong.

Comment: @melpomene I would really like to know why scanf("%s", string) is wrong. I know that if I hit the "tab" button it wont take my string really good, but then I use gets! If I should never use gets, then what other option there is?

Comment: @user1908349 `scanf %s` has the same problem as `gets`: It doesn't (and can't) check how long the target buffer is, so it will cause a buffer overflow if the input is too long. Your other options are `fgets`, `fgetc`, and `fread`, basically.

Comment: You can also use `scanf("%49s", cr[nr].mark);` to limit the input to 49 non-blank characters plus the terminal null, which just fit into the array of length 50.  However, the big downside of `scanf()` is working out whether the string got truncated, and what to do with it.  Generally, you're best off using `fgets()` of an equivalent (along with a buffer size like 4096) to read the line; you can then use `sscanf()` to parse the information.  Note, too, the `%s` stops reading at white space; you can't have blanks in the name you're reading.

Comment: @melpomene: I have to disagree.  It does not make Windows wrong.  It simply means that Windows has a sensible but non-standard extension over the standard.  Linux has hundreds of APIs that are non-standard extensions over the standard too.  It isn't wrong to produce a documented, compatible extension.  It isn't wrong to exploit such an extension (though if you're going to have to port your code, you need to know you have used a non-portable extension).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think this extension is sensible. In fact, I expect it to do weird things with read+write filehandles or input redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Your `maximum` function doesn't make any sense. You're trying to use an object type as an item for a struct, using superfluous pointer arithmetic and other things that were already discussed in the comments in your post.

```
void maximum(car *cr, int nr)
{
    int i, max = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= nr - 1; i++)
    {
        if(cr[i].cilinderCap >= cr[max].cilinderCap)
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    display(cr, max);
}
```

<sup>Note: try to understand my code before copying it to your file.</sup>

This is the most intuitive approach one can get. Note I'm using the "cylinder capacity" variable to actually check, uhm, the maximum cylinder capacity.

Also note that if you start your cars at index 0, you should search up to `n - 1`, and not `n`. The referenced parameter for `nr` is also redundant, as you don't even try to modify it.

So, you just call:

```
maximum(cr, n);
```

Another thing is that you should check for errors in the function, as in its current state, it might crash if there are no elements in the list.

There are some other "ethically incorrect stuff" in your code that are irrelevant to the question, but I recommend reading some articles on Google about struct lists.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation. I consider that the stuff they teach us at the school are really useless compared to the things that I have seen in other books. I have started reading K. N. Kings book about C and it makes a lot of what I know much easier.
But since we have only one semester of c, and we have one class of 2 hours once a week it's a little hard to learn from the book at the same time. I knew that fflush(stdin) is wrong, and when I asked my teacher about it, she said that she needs to look on the internet about it.

Comment: I guess that google does a better job than a teacher these days.